# Volume up key to answer call

Tags: calls, volume-control, buttons, volume, call-screening

I'm running Android device on version 5.1 and my device doesn't have any buttons except power and volume.

I want my volume up key to answer incoming calls. Is there any exposed or any other method to help facilitate the ask?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with Tasker;

**Now for the Task:**

*Task 1 Answering the call*

Create a named task :

Action: Phone >> Take Call

[image: a] [image: b]
<sup>(click images for larger variants)</sup>

Exit out of the task.

Task 2

*Ending the phone call*

Create another named task:

Acion: Action: Phone >> End Call

[image: a] [image: b]

**Create a new Profile**

State >> Hardware >> Button [Next] (which is similar to volume up) Check Stop Event.

[image: a] [image: b]

[image: c] [image: d]

For the second profile the proccedure is the same but this time a media button used is "previous" instead of "next".

[image: a]

Activate all profiles

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) is one option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn.

---

Using <kbd>Power key</kbd>- you can set how many times you want to toggle to answer, here it is 3 times

[image]

---

Using <kbd>Vol</kbd>

[image]

You can use either methods that suit you