# How to unlock Android phone when someone is calling, without picking up?

Tags: lock-screens, calls, android-12, motorola

When someone is calling, a round slider appears at the bottom of the screen and I have to slide down to reject or slide up to pick up. The slider appears in the same place as the under-screen fingerprint sensor. The unlocking pattern also doesn't seem to be accessible.

Is there any way to normally unlock Android 12 when it is still ringing?

Comment: Try pulling down the Notification bar and tap on Settings icon when the phone is ringing. Does that show lockscreen? If it does, you should be able to unlock the phone and the incoming call might automatically reduce to a heads-up notification.

Comment: Have you checked out the solution presented in this question? 
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171947/volume-up-key-to-answer-call